# Migrating from Heroku to fly.io + Supabase : "Failed due to unhealthy allocations"

Tags: postgresql, devops, supabase, fly

I'm trying to move from Heroku to Fly.io + Supabase.

I managed to have my app working on fly.io when connected to the postgres database of my heroku app, using the command:

```
fly secrets set DATABASE_URL="XXX"
```

where XXX is the value of the `DATABASE_URL` found in the *config vars* of the settings of my heroku app, which looks like `postgres://....`

great !

Now I'm trying to replace it with the Connection (Pooling) String from my Supabase database settings :

```
fly secrets set DATABASE_URL="postgres://[USER]:[PWD]@[SERVER]:6543/[DBNAME]"
```

But then, I get

> --> v11 failed - Failed due to unhealthy allocations - rolling back to job version 10 and deploying as v12.

I'm certain that my Supabase database password is okay since I'm able to connect to it in my terminal using

```
psql -h [HOST] -p 6543 -d [DBNAME] -U [USER]
```

I also tested to add the domains of my app (both my real app URL and my fly.io url) in *Supabase > Settings > Redirect URLs*, but it is not working either : I still get the same error.

If I rollback to my Heroku database URL, it works.

So it seems that my app CAN work on fly.io, but that there is an error connecting to Supabase, correct ?

Does anyone have a clue of how achieving this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this was due because of my database password containing special characters - [as mentionned in the documentation of Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/managing-passwords).
After I have URL-encoded it, it works fine !